# Additional function is executed when enter or space is pressed when it shouldn't in simulated keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simulated keyboard in html. There are buttons forming a keyboard on the screen. When they are clicked the character assigned to that button is appended to a text element on the screen. Using the actual irl keyboard is possible too, working in the same manner.

The problem is that when I click on an onscreen button and then press the irl spacebar or enter buttons, that onscreen button character is repeated after the space or enter. **This happens with space and enter only**, and only with the irl keyboard press in combination with an on-screen button click.

Here is a code snippet that shows the bug. Click on the running snippet area so it can listen to your keyboard. Type on the keyboard and the text is displayed on the screen; it is fine. But then click the 'a' button followed by a real keyboard spacebar press, the 'a' repeats.

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress',function(e) {
  // console.log(e.key);
  keyClick(e.key);
}
);

function keyPress(key) {
  if (key == "Space") {
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent + " ";
  }
}
function keyClick(key) {
  // console.log("poop");
   if (key == "Space") {
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent + " ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent + key;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="text"></div>
  <button id="a" onClick="keyClick(this.id)">a</button>
</body>
```

I started with the irl keyboard and the html keyboard using different functions so I thought that might be the issue. I tried combining them into one and the same issue persists. I added a parameter to the function that tells where the function is called from and strangley when I press the irl spacebar it shows that the extraneous character is being called from the html button's onclick. I feel like I'm missing something obvious or I've found a weird bug.

Comment: @Pointy I tried separating the keyboard presses and screen clicks to be handled in different functions and same issue happened. Also, the extraneous function call is coming from a click, not a press. If the event listener were the issue, wouldn't the extra call come from a press, and also wouldn't the issue occur for all characters, not only space and enter?

Comment: Could you minimise the code to provide a runnable snippet which shows the problem See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you, I made a code snippet that shows the bug and replaced the code with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because if the button is still in focus and the space bar is pressed a click event is fired as well as the keypress event

This snippet sets a flag to remember if the last key pressed was a space, and if so ignores the next click.

Note: some of the code in the question related to 'Space' was never called and this snippet removes it.

```html
<body>
  <div id="text"></div>
  <button id="a" onClick="if (!lastKeyWasKeypressedSpace) {keyClick(this.id);} else {lastKeyWasKeypressedSpace = false;}">a</button>
</body>
<script>
  let lastKeyWasKeypressedSpace = false;
  window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    keyClick(e.key);
    lastKeyWasKeypressedSpace = e.key == ' ';
  });

  function keyClick(key) {
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent + key;
  }
</script>
```

Note also that you will need to decide what you want to happen on the enter key being pressed, but that is outside the scope of this question.

ADDITION:

While I cannot replicate the situation described in the comments (the problem of using the button after keyboard and space input), one suggestion would be to dispense with the use of button and use straight divs instead.

This gets round the problem of space [and enter] being special in terms of creating onclick events.

Here's a simple snippet to demonstrate:

```html
<style>
  .key {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: solid 1px black;
    bordeer-radis: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px 2px 5px;
  }
  
  .key:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="text"></div>
  <div id="a" onClick="keyClick(this.id);" class="key">a</div>
</body>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    keyClick(e.key);
  });

  function keyClick(key) {
    document.getElementById('text').textContent = document.getElementById('text').textContent + key;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I never suspected that html would work in such a way, thank you for identifying the problem. There must be something built in to space and enter to mean repeat (because in some instances that must be helpful and not idiotic).

Comment: It isn't exactly repeat - what's happening is that the keypress fires a click event as well.

Comment: The solution you offered however is flawed. If I am typing with the irl keyboard and hit space, then want to use the on screen buttons, the first click will be ignored and I will have to press the same button twice to write a single character. It seems that if there is no way to modify the annoying property of space directly, there will be no clean solution to this, although I have seen simulated keyboards without this issue.

Comment: Are  you sure that what you describe is happening for you it doesn't happen for me. What browseer/system are you using?

Comment: I am using firefox. I double checked on edge and it is happening there as well.

Comment: There wouldn't be a way to, once a keyboard event is detected, deselect all elements in the document?

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to replicate the problem stated. However, getting rid of buttons and replacing with straight divs (ie not giving the  system the  chance to do anything on a focussed element) might be a simple way forward. I've added another snippet to demonstrate.

Comment: Yes that is a good response, especially if the active state isn't need for css or functionality. Thank you.